# Exclude Tests from Maven build

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-3

When I am running `maven clean install` it always executes all tests in `src/test/java` is there a way to skip all the tests, just to run simple build without any tests.

I want my tests to be in `src/test/java` but I want to tell maven to do not execute them. I've been looking for something like that on the internet but I did not manage to find the answer.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try with:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Source  [Maven Surefire Plugin - Skipping Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html).

Answer (score 21):

You can also choose to use

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip
```

From [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)  website:

> If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.

As is says you will not even compile the test sources.

Comment: True is that -DskipTests didn't work for me and yours worked!

Answer (score 7):

From http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

use this

> mvn clean install -DskipTests

Answer (score 4):

My favorite way to manage when my tests run is to create a Maven variable called `skip-tests` and default it to `true`. Then you can use that variable like so:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>${skip-tests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This way, you can just pass in the variable at build time, `-Dskip-tests=false`, when you don't want them to run. This is most useful when you have integration *and* unit tests, and would like to run or disable both sets of tests with just one variable.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers here are correct. To be precise,

**-DskipTests** - compiles the test classes, but skips running them,
**-Dmaven.test.skip=true**  - skips compiling the test files and also does not run them

Answer (score 0):

We use Surefire for Unit tests, and [Failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for Integration tests.

To skip all tests:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

To skip just Failsafe tests:

```
mvn clean package -DskipIT
```

To skip just Surefire, you need to explicitly call the integration-test goal of the Failsafe plugin, after compiling the test classes of course:

```
mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test
```

Answer (score -1):

I think simplest would be this : `mvn clean package -Dmaven.skip.tests=true`

I think this the approach to use as it does not make you change your pom, so does not have to make changes to the project.

Comment: It's -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: That skips compiling tests, see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html